# SQL Trigger Error ORA-04098

Tags: sql, oracle

i have two tables named as childs and parent.

```
create table parent(
    wallet_id NUMBER generated always as identity,
    amount int,
    customer_id int,
    primary key(wallet_id),
    Foreign key (customer_id) REFERENCES childs(customer_id) 
);

create table childs(
    customer_id number generated always as identity,
    name varchar2 (255)
);
```

Now what i wanted to achieve was to get name from childs , and assign a wallet_id to childs in parent table as parent table has a foreign key to customer_id.
For this purpose i created a trigger.

```
create or replace 
TRIGGER TRIGGER1 
AFTER INSERT ON CHILDS 
Declare 
id int;
BEGIN
select MAX(customer_id) into id FROM childs;
insert into parent (customer_id ) values ( id );

END;
```

Now trigger is created but when i insert value in childs,

> insert into childs(names) values ('jarral');

Now following error appears:

> SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSTEM.TRG' is invalid and failed re-validation
>   04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
>   *Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
>              found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
>              failed for the trigger.
>   *Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
>              disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.

How can i solve that?

Comment: What are the compilation errors? ORA-04098 just tells us that it's invalid. By the way, why is `childs` the parent of `parent`? And your definition is missing a primary/unique key for the FK on `parent` to refer to, and the `system` schema is reserved for Oracle internal objects that you are not supposed to go near. Aside from that, the trigger creates without error. Your `insert` statement refers to a column called `names` that doesn't exist, but otherwise runs fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I follow your question, but is this what you are after ?

```
SQL> create table t1 ( id number generated as identity , x int);

Table created.

SQL> create table t2 ( id number generated as identity , t1_id int);

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace
  2  trigger trg
  3  after insert on t1
  4  for each row
  5  begin
  6    insert into t2 (t1_id) values ( :new.id);
  7  end;
  8  /

Trigger created.

SQL> insert into t1 (x) values ( 0);

1 row created.

SQL> select * from t1;

        ID          X
---------- ----------
         1          0

SQL> select * from t2;

        ID      T1_ID
---------- ----------
         1          1
```